# Keeping different headlines using only one button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dry

So I'm just getting familiar with DOM and JavaScript in general. I'm playing with this little code, where you have all the headers, paragraph in html, and just simply clicking on a button, JavaScript will change all the text to the same color. But I can't find any way to not repeat myself. Can you guys help me out, if there is any smart way? Even to loop or anything?
Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="main_content">
<h1 id="heading_1">Hello World</h1>
<h2 id="heading_2">Hello World</h2>
<h3 id="heading_3">Hello World</h3>
<h4 id="heading_4">Hello World</h4>
<h5 id="heading_5">Hello World</h5>
<h6 id="heading_6">Hello World</h6>
<p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum ipsum and ipsum and some ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="value_color">
<button id="myButton">Check the font color!</button>

var heading_1 = document.getElementById("heading_1");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
var value_color = document.getElementById("value_color");

button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
heading_1.style.color = value_color.value;
heading_2.style.color = value_color.value;
heading_3.style.color = value_color.value;
heading_4.style.color = value_color.value;
heading_5.style.color = value_color.value;
heading_6.style.color = value_color.value;
});
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are trying to do here?  Not exactly sure what "way to not repeat myself" is referring to.

Comment: As you can see at the event listener, I keep repeating pretty much the same line. heading_1.style.color, heading_2.style.color... etc. That's what I'm refering to.

Comment: Ah ok then this is a selector issue.  As answered you could apply a similar class to all items and call that or if you wanted to call a collection of ids you could do something like: document.querySelectorAll("heading_1, heading_2, heading_3, ... ") or $("heading_1, heading_2, heading_3, ... ")

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to select your headers using class instead of an id.

```
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName("chameleon-header");
for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  headers[i].style.color = value_color.value;
}

<h1 id="heading_1" class="chameleon-header">Hello World</h1>
<h2 id="heading_2" class="chameleon-header">Hello World</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped a lot!

Comment: You are welcome @GondaPapa. If you could accept my answer that'd be great.